# Passing 2dim array through an median function to the one of 2 other function

Tags: visual-c++

I want  to use one median function "selectfunction" to choose one of the 2 other functions at random to pass my 2-dim array to the selected function. There is a problem in the median function please help.

```
#include <iostream>

#define random(x)(rand()%x) // for random number between numbers of  0 and 1

using namespace std;

void proc1 (int iArray[][2]);
void proc2 (int iArray[][2]);
void selectfunction(int iArray[][2]);

int A[4][2] = {{1, 2} , {3, 4} , { 5, 7} , {8, 1} };


void proc1(int iArray[][2])
{
    int i= 0;
    for (i= 0; i< 4 ; i++)
    {
    cout << iArray[i][0]<< endl;
    }   

}
void proc2(int iArray[][2])
{
    int i= 0;
    for (i= 0; i< 4 ; i++)
    {
       cout << iArray[i][1] << endl;
    }   

} 

void selectfunction(int iArray[][2])
{
int randmix = random(2);
    switch (randmix)
    {
        case 0:
                proc1(int iArray[][2]);
                break;
        case 1:
                proc2(int iArray[][2]);
                break;
    default:
        break;

    } 

}

int main ()
{

    selectfunction(A);
    cin;
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Can you use STL containers such as `vector`?  That would make things much tidier.

Comment: it could be an alternative response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    case 0:
            proc1(int iArray[][2]);
            break;
```

The call should be simply `proc1(iArray);`. You already know enough to write `selectfunction(A);` and not `selectfunction(int A[][2]);` - you should call `proc1` and `proc2` the same way.

Also, the statement `cin;`: I'm not sure what you wanted it to do, but be aware that it does nothing at all.